# How can I display tabs and spaces in Doom Emacs?

Tags: doom, whitespace, tabs, whitespace-mode

I have tried `M-x whitespace-mode` but it does not do anything.

Comment: It seems like doom emacs have specific logic for whitespace-mode: `doom-highlight-non-default-indentation-h`, try to override this and enable `whitespace-mode`? `(advice-add #'doom-highlight-non-default-indentation-h :override #'ignore)`

Comment: What is the value of `whitespace-style`?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet worked for me:

```
;; source: https://tech.tonyballantyne.com/2023/01/23/whitespace-mode/
(use-package! whitespace
  :config
  (setq
    whitespace-style '(face tabs tab-mark spaces space-mark trailing newline newline-mark)
    whitespace-display-mappings '(
      (space-mark   ?\     [?\u00B7]     [?.])
      (space-mark   ?\xA0  [?\u00A4]     [?_])
      (newline-mark ?\n    [182 ?\n])
      (tab-mark     ?\t    [?\u00BB ?\t] [?\\ ?\t])))
  (global-whitespace-mode +1))
```